# Are there clip arts for LibreOffice or OpenOffice?

Tags: debian, openoffice, libreoffice

Is there a standard set of clip arts for LibreOffice (or OpenOffice), like the ones coming with Microsoft Office?

I am running Debian and LibreOffice from the standard repository, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the openclipart package from the Debian repository (available for lenny, squeeze, wheezy, sid).

The clip art is accessed via the `Tools/Gallery` menu entry.